# Google Maps API v3; draw a polygon to outline a collection of markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon, google-maps-markers

I've got a lot of map markers grouped in various areas (of the UK) like this...
http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/waypoints/download/?area=1D (ignore the grey markers)

I'd like to use this marker coordinate data to be able to construct a simple polygon **around** the group of markers in each area (rather than just connecting them all together - which makes a messy hedgehoggy-star of a shape). And then i wish to use the various polygons on a larger map to form an "index" for these groups of marker pages.

Do you know if this is even possible? and if so how i might approach the issue?

Comment: Are your markers dynamic or constant?  I.e. do you need to calculate which markers you want to use as endpoints of your polygon at runtime, or can you specify that manually?

Comment: I guess they are dynamic markers so it would be nice if we could calculate the start/finish point for each group of markers.

Comment: Ok i finally gave up and manually created each polygon

Comment: Could this be the answer to what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415143/how-would-i-make-a-polygon-based-on-the-relative-positions-of-markers-in-google

Comment: Yep that is exactly what i wanted - ta