# How would I make a polygon based on the relative positions of markers in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a list of markers that I want to create a polygon around (showing the area around the markers and not the markers themselves). So instead of having the poly points be the direct lat/long of the markers, I want the poly to "wrap" around the markers to show the relative area around them.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a **convex hull**. There's an example at http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_ConvexHull.asp which uses the algorithm described at http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0203/algorithm_0203.htm

Comment: But would it allow me to automatically draw the overlay around a set of markers/coordinates? Like if I had a set of markers, I want to draw a poly around the markers but not using the actual marker points as poly points, but instead drawing AROUND the markers. Sort of like highlighting them.

Comment: One way of doing that would be to construct "virtual" markers around each marker, forming a circle of "virtual" markers (that is, draw a circle centred on each real marker; the points forming the circle are "virtual" markers). Then pass all the "virtual" markers to the convex-hull routine. The polygon would be drawn around the shape formed by the "virtual" markers rather than the real ones. This isn't particularly efficient though: you could have thousands of "virtual" markers instead of tens of real ones.